# certain keys pressed event

Tags: c#, winforms

im doing some work on a project that i need to pass my final exam.
So i choosed C#, Windows Forms, and i have something in my mind.
I need to help with event where i press keys on keyboard that represent word. 
(like h-e-l-l-o) and if the keys will be pressed in this order something will happen, that i can figure out by myself, but i need help with the keypressed method or something.

TL;DR: I need help with event on my WinForm app that will work like when you type "AWESOME" to nowhere on youtube.

Comment: Go into the KeyUp or KeyDown method of the active control and then on the EventArgs that get passed you can do something like `if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A) //DoStuff`

Comment: Take a look at this sample: [How to: Handle Keyboard Input at the Form Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hook to the KeyPressed event, add the pressed key to a list, check the content of the list to see if it matches any of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from a project. Hook a function to the KeyPress event of the textfield. you can get the full contents inside the function or just the last pressed character.

```
private void IsKeyPressNumber(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9'))
        e.Handled = true;
}

this.txtCode.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.IsKeyPressNumber);
```